# Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb Windows 10 AWS Workspaces

Tags: windows, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, anaconda

I have installed anaconda Python 2.7 on my AWS workspace with Windows 10 and I launch Jupyter Notebook from the anaconda command prompt. When I try to create a new notebook, I have an error: 
[I 20:20:23.697 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[W 20:20:23.795 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (::1): Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb
[W 20:20:23.796 NotebookApp] Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb

Could you please help? I have tried to look for a solution but it is not clear what needs to be done for Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not using AWS, but maybe this can help:

When I launched

```
jupyter notebook
```

from the anaconda command prompt, while starting up one of the first lines in the log in that command prompt window said:

```
[I <some timestamp> NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\
```

Unfortunately, I don't have permissions to write into the C:\ directory.

So I generated a configuration file

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

that ended up as *jupyter_notebook_config.py* in

```
%USERPROFILE%\.jupyter
```

Use

```
jupyter --paths
```

to see which directories your Jupyter on AWS is searching for config files.

Finally, in that config file there is a line you can comment out and point to the directory that should contain your notebooks (and kernels):

```
## The directory to use for notebooks and kernels.
#c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = ''
```

Of course, make sure the directory that you mention on that line is actually (created and) writeable by you.

Comment: This worked for me. The issue I was facing was i work on a corporate laptop with several restrictions. Changing the path to a folder I created on desktop worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You should just need to ensure that you (or more specifically the user running the program) has write-permissions on the folder where the new file `Untitled.ipynb` is being created. See [this page on changing Windows 10 folder permissions for details](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/set-file-folder-permissions-windows/).