# Jupyter problem to launch notebook (permission denied)

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I have installed Jupyter on my desktop and try to launch a Python notebook.
I have a permission denied error and on the server side the following error.
403 POST /api/contents (::1): Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb

This never worked on my desktop which belongs to my company.
This problem may be related to a security problem ?

Thank you very much for your help.
Kamran

Answer (score 3):

You(the user running Jupyter) will need write permissions to the folder where the Untitled.ipynb is located.

May be duplicate, and explains folder permissions:

[earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54837390/12534623)

Comment: Excellent, your solution solved my problem. Actually i had no .jupyter file, I created one and changed the working directory for the notebook in a place where i had the right permissions. Thank you a lot.

Comment: great :) hope you have a good start with Jupyter, feel free to upvote :)